# How to add hours to a time field

Tags: amazon-redshift

In amazon redshift I would like to add number of hours to a time field

```
tt_time     hours_add
12:00:00    1
15:30:00    3
16:00:00    6

Expected Output
13:00:00
18:00:00
22:00:00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the **DATEADD** Redshift function, using "h", "hr" or "hrs" as your first parameter. Documentation for this function can be found [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEADD_function.html) and [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_Dateparts_for_datetime_functions.html).

This sql statement should work for you, assuming you want to create a new table to hold your results:

```
INSERT into new_table_name SELECT DATEADD(hr,hours_add,tt_time) FROM current_table_name;
```